# Check whether the order is in the shopping cart based on the order ID

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When an order is pending payment, The same order remains in the cart, How to check if the same order remains in the cart or not? For example, based on the order ID, check whether the order is in the shopping cart.

I want to display a message on order-pay page if the same order ID is still in the cart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a little trouble understanding what you need, because `WC_Cart` objects essentially don't contain `WC_Order` objects in any form.

If you need to detect on `order-pay` page **whether the current cart is associated to that specific order**, you can call and compare `get_cart_hash()` values of `WC_Order` object with the cart hash value from WooCommerce session.

You can do such comparison in `order-pay` template like this:

```
$order_cart_hash = $order->get_cart_hash();
$session_cart_hash = WC()->cart->get_cart_hash();

if( $order_cart_hash === $session_cart_hash ) {
    // Yep, current cart is associated to this unpaid order
}
```

**Note:** This comparison is safe. If the customer updates the cart in any way, session cart hash is altered. And if he then change the cart back to it's original state, the hash values will match again.